# Problem in dynamically binding data to html using jquery

Tags: jquery, api

We are trying to bind data from an api dynamically in html using jquery. We have an api which gives data in the json format like this

[image]

Our html file has the following code

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('start');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'https://localhost:44361/api/pdfcreator/GetEmployees',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                        $('#student').append("<tr><td>" + item.Name + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.LastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.Age + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.Gender + "</td></tr>");
                    });
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                },
                error: function (x, e) {
                    alert(x.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

& also this

```
       <table id="student" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1" width="400px">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: gray; color: white">Name</td>
                <td style="background-color: gray; color: white">LastName</td>
                <td style="background-color: gray; color: white">Age</td>
                <td style="background-color: gray; color:white">Gender</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

But when the html is viewed in browser it looks like this

[image]

As you see the data from the api is not shown here. In the browser it also shows the following error message

[image]

Can anyone please tell us what exactly are we missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Use `http` -> `url: http://localhost:44361/api/pdfcreator/GetEmployees`

Comment: The `OPTIONS` in the error implies that the browser believes this is a cross-domain request, which is then failing. If it's a local request, make the path relative to the root of the site, not an absolute URI, eg. `url: '/api/pdfcreator/GetEmployees'`

Comment: Looks like your server can't find the requested URI

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - tried giving '/api/pdfcreator/GetEmployees' but it did not work. The html file we have is not a part of the same site. It is a separate file.

Comment: In that case if you're making a cross-domain request you need to modify the response so that it includes CORS headers. Client-side JS cannot make a request to a remote endpoint without them

Comment: I tried by giving `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`. It now takes little time to process. But the data does not come up. We are receiving this error now-- **GET http://localhost:44361/api/pdfcreator/GetEmployees net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**.